# Make individual angular-gridster items resizable and draggable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, resize, gridster

So I'm using Angular-gridster for a dashboard feel to my Angular app.

Each of the individual widgets or items in the dashboard can be minimized, maximized, closed. They can also be dragged and moved around.

When I minimize a widget, I've noticed that it's still resizable, and I just drag the bottom of the widget to any size, without it reloading the widget.

It looks like this: [image: Min widget resized]

It looks like the resizable property is set to all of gridster opts, so I need another way to go about it. Any suggestions on how to best go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution yet for my task.
But if you need to do it quick - you can do the trick:

```css
/* hide all resize-handlers */
.resize-trick .gridster-item-resizable-handler { display: none; }

/* show one if wee need */
.resize-trick.resize-only-height .gridster-item-resizable-handler.handle-s { display: block; }
```

```html
<li ... class="resize-trick resize-only-height"> 
There is your widgets ng-repeat...
Angular Gridster add handler elements for resize.
But you can just hide some of it using CSS :3

<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-s"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-e"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-n"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-w"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-se"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-ne"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-sw"></div>
<div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-nw"></div>

</li>
```